# css counter-increment unwanted reset when skipping :before

Tags: html, css, css-counter

Im having a problem with my counter that im using to get numbers before h3, h4 and h5, like a list. The number should only be visible if the tag has class="count", and its only then it should counter-reset for the header below.

When i skip showing the number on a h3 the h4s counter gets messed upp, and same for skipping h4. Does anyone have any idea why?

```css
body {
  counter-reset: h3
}
h3 {
  counter-reset: h4
}
h4 {
  counter-reset: h5
}
h3.count:before {
  counter-increment: h3;
  content: counter(h3) ". "
}
h4.count:before {
  counter-increment: h4;
  content: counter(h3) "." counter(h4) ". "
}
h5.count:before {
  counter-increment: h5;
  content: counter(h3) "." counter(h4) "." counter(h5) ". "
}
h3:before,
h4:before,
h5:before {
  content: "";
  counter-increment: none
}
```

```html
<h3 class="count">: should be : 1</h3>
<h4 class="count">: should be : 1.1</h4>
<h5 class="count">: should be : 1.1.1</h5>
<h5>No counter</h5>
<h5 class="count">: should be : 1.1.2</h5>
<h4>No counter</h4>
<h5 class="count">: should be : <span style="color: #ff0000">1.1.3</span></h5>
<h5>No counter</h5>
<h5 class="count">: should be : <span style="color: #ff0000">1.1.4</span></h5>
<h4 class="count">: should be : 1.2</h4>
<h3>No counter</h3>
<h4 class="count">: should be : <span style="color: #ff0000">1.3</span></h4>
<h5 class="count">: should be : <span style="color: #ff0000">1.3.1</span></h5>
<h5>No counter</h5>
<h5 class="count">: should be : <span style="color: #ff0000">1.3.2</span></h5>
<h4>No counter</h4>
<h5 class="count">: should be : <span style="color: #ff0000">1.3.3</span></h5>
<h5>No counter</h5>
<h5 class="count">: should be : <span style="color: #ff0000">1.3.4</span></h5>
<h4 class="count">: should be : <span style="color: #ff0000">1.4</span></h4>
<h3 class="count">: should be : 2</h3>
<h5 class="count">: should be : 2.0.1</h5>
<h4 class="count">: should be : 2.1</h4>
<h5 class="count">: should be : 2.1.1</h5>
<h5>No counter</h5>
<h5 class="count">: should be : 2.1.2</h5>
```

css

```
body {counter-reset: h3}
h3 {counter-reset: h4}
h4 {counter-reset: h5}

h3.count:before { counter-increment: h3; content: counter(h3) ". "}
h4.count:before { counter-increment: h4; content: counter(h3) "." counter(h4) ". "}
h5.count:before { counter-increment: h5; content: counter(h3) "." counter(h4) "." counter(h5) ". "}

h3:before, 
h4:before, 
h5:before{ content: ""; counter-increment: none }
```

html

```
<h3 class="count">: should be : 1</h3>
<h4 class="count">: should be : 1.1</h4>
<h5 class="count">: should be : 1.1.1</h5>
<h5>No counter</h5>
<h5 class="count">: should be : 1.1.2</h5>
<h4>No counter</h4>
<h5 class="count">: should be : 1.1.3</span></h5>
<h5>No counter</h5>
<h5 class="count">: should be : 1.1.4</span></h5>
<h4 class="count">: should be : 1.2</h4>
```

result

```
1. : should be : 1
1.1. : should be : 1.1
1.1.1. : should be : 1.1.1
No counter
1.1.2. : should be : 1.1.2
No counter
1.1.1. : should be : 1.1.3
No counter
1.1.2. : should be : 1.1.4
1.2. : should be : 1.2
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/6gj2r1jd/

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6gj2r1jd/1/) what you wanted to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per your CSS code for the counter, the value of `h5` counter should be reset whenever you encounter an `h4` tag.

```
body {counter-reset: h3}
h3 {counter-reset: h4}
h4 {counter-reset: h5} /* this one */
```

Because of the above code, when the browser encounters the `h4` tag with no class (and content as **No Counter**) the counter value of `h5` counter gets reset back to 0. This is the reason why instead of **1.1.3** you had got the value as **1.1.1**

```
<h5 class="count">: should be : 1.1.2</h5>
<h4>No counter</h4> <!-- This line would cause h5 counter to reset -->
<h5 class="count">: should be : 1.1.3</span></h5>
```

If my understanding of your question is correct, what you actually need is to reset the counter only when the heading tags have `class="count"`. Hence, modifying the counter-reset CSS code like below should solve the problem.

```
h3.count {counter-reset: h4}
h4.count {counter-reset: h5}
```

```css
body {
  counter-reset: h3
}
h3.count {
  counter-reset: h4
}
h4.count {
  counter-reset: h5
}
h3.count:before {
  counter-increment: h3;
  content: counter(h3)". "
}
h4.count:before {
  counter-increment: h4;
  content: counter(h3)"." counter(h4)". "
}
h5.count:before {
  counter-increment: h5;
  content: counter(h3)"." counter(h4)"." counter(h5)". "
}
h3:before,
h4:before,
h5:before {
  content: "";
  counter-increment: none
}
```

```html
<h3 class="count">: should be : 1</h3>
<h4 class="count">: should be : 1.1</h4>
<h5 class="count">: should be : 1.1.1</h5>
<h5>No counter</h5>
<h5 class="count">: should be : 1.1.2</h5>
<h4>No counter</h4>
<h5 class="count">: should be : <span style="color: #ff0000">1.1.3</span></h5>
<h5>No counter</h5>
<h5 class="count">: should be : <span style="color: #ff0000">1.1.4</span></h5>
<h4 class="count">: should be : 1.2</h4>

<h3>No counter</h3>
<h4 class="count">: should be : <span style="color: #ff0000">1.3</span></h4>
<h5 class="count">: should be : <span style="color: #ff0000">1.3.1</span></h5>
<h5>No counter</h5>
<h5 class="count">: should be : <span style="color: #ff0000">1.3.2</span></h5>
<h4>No counter</h4>
<h5 class="count">: should be : <span style="color: #ff0000">1.3.3</span></h5>
<h5>No counter</h5>
<h5 class="count">: should be : <span style="color: #ff0000">1.3.4</span></h5>
<h4 class="count">: should be : <span style="color: #ff0000">1.4</span></h4>

<h3 class="count">: should be : 2</h3>
<h5 class="count">: should be : 2.0.1</h5>
<h4 class="count">: should be : 2.1</h4>
<h5 class="count">: should be : 2.1.1</h5>
<h5>No counter</h5>
<h5 class="count">: should be : 2.1.2</h5>
```

Comment: Yes that works for it :) 
But now i have another problem when im trying to integrate it in my code. I dont know if i should update my question, but here is the fiddle for the code that does not work for me at the moment...
http://jsfiddle.net/3eact7tx/

Comment: @SannaWidell: I am looking into that and will let you know if I find a solution but you shouldn't update this question. Instead you should create a separate question for the new problem and doing so will open up the question for the rest of the community to contribute too.

Comment: @SannaWidell: The level of nesting is also important when using counters and I think your current structure and counter definitions would not work as  you need. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/3eact7tx/1/) might work for you. Please note how I have added a class to the `div` and defined the counter on it.